# Stackoverflow Exception on DefaultValue attribute of class type

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, stack-overflow, default-value

I've been using the 'defaultvalue' attribute on my member properties of my application.  I'd like to move the 'defaultvalue' attribute to the type definition itself, to remove hundreds of lines of code.

My definition looks like this:

```
   [DefaultValue(typeof(RTDDLocation), "Class.Object.Attribute")]
   public class RTDDLocation :
      IEquatable<RTDDLocation>,
      ICloneable
```

When I debug this, it causes a StackOverflow exception, because checking type becomes recursive.

Is it possible to get a resolution for this, or is what I'm doing impossible?

Edit: I should add that I am using this in the context of a property grid.  I want the default values to show whether or not the propertyname should be marked as bold or not.

Thanks!

Comment: DefaultValue by itself does not set anything - see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). There must be some code somewhere that reads it and sets the value. Are you using a library to do this? Which one?

Comment: Am I missing something or wouldn't you be the one to handle the attribute? Meaning that your attribute is just an attribute, till something utilizes it.

Comment: I'm using my class with propertygrids.  I'm using the defaultvalue attribute so the property grid will shown any value that is not 'default' as bold.  I understand what the attribute is used for and how it works.   I was pretty sure the default value attibute can be used on a type, but cause the stackoverflow exception when used in conjunction with a property grid.

Comment: @greggorob64 - You should add that bit about the property grid to your question so people will know the context in which you are trying to use the attribute.  It might help you get better answers.